# Is it possible to ORDER BY similar strings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a column containing text input from various users around the world and I would like to group them so that strings that are similar to each other are closer together. The column contains strings that are in languages other than English and in addition can contain misspelled words.

I have been looking into N-grams and Levenshtein distance but those seem to require that I have a string in mind to match the rows against.

As an example, I would like

```
   |Comcast               | 
   |how to play basketball|
   |Walmart               |
   |www.Comcast.net       |
   |Wamlart               |
   |basketball            |
```

to end up looking like:

```
   |Comcast               | 
   |www.Comcast.net       |
   |how to play basketball|
   |basketball            |
   |Walmart               |
   |Wamlart               |
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not `GROUP BY`, it's `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

You could try ordering by [`SOUNDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) code.

E.g.,

```
ORDER BY SOUNDEX(MyColumn)
```

This will break down on longer strings, however. You will probably have better luck using the Double Metaphone algorithm:

http://www.atomodo.com/code/double-metaphone/metaphone.sql/view

Comment: +1 for soundex(), that's pretty neat. Tho also worth noting for OP: `This function, as currently implemented, is intended to work well with strings that are in the English language only. Strings in other languages may not produce reliable results.`

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly! Is there a way to resolve the fact that Comcast and www.comcast.net would not be placed near each other under this method?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column ASC
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column DESC
```

The column will be ordered alphabetically ascending or descending

Answer (score 0):

If all the strings have things to remove like '.net' before displaying the data, you could pull off something like this:

```
SELECT column,ordercolumn FROM 
(
    SELECT column,REPLACE(column,'www.comcast.net','ComCast') ordercolumn
    FROM mytable
) A
ORDER BY ordercolumn,column;
```